# In a UIScrollView with a large number of tappable image views, what's a good way to improve performance?

Tags: ios, uikit

There are 100+ image views, and each needs to be tappable. The fact that each has a tap gesture recognizer attached to it has hurt performance. What would be a good strategy for reducing the number of tap gestures, or improving performance?

Rewriting it as a collection view would be too high risk at the moment.

Comment: Using a UICollectionView is exactly what you should do. Why is it high risk? A collection view is basically a far more optimized scroll view where only relevant cells need to be loaded. This means you only load a few images at a time instead of all. It also means you don't need any gesture recognizers. So much better.

Comment: The scroll view is a fundamental part of the app, with complex existing behavior underneath it, and is years old.

Comment: If you're dead set against a collection view, you still don't need lots of gesture recognizers. Just add 1 to the scroll view. It would be simple to determine the actual image from the coordinates of the tap. Or have your custom tappable image view class extend `touchesEnded` which can in turn call a delegate or closure saying "I've been tapped".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It feels strange that multiple tap gestures would cause you harm but you can get away with a simple single gesture recogniser doing something like the following:

```
class ContainerView: UIView {
    
    @IBOutlet private var scrollView: UIScrollView?
    @IBOutlet private var imageViews: [UIImageView]?
    
    private func attachTapGestureRecogniser() {
        addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onImageTapped)))
    }
    
    @objc private func onImageTapped(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        guard let tappedImageIndex = imageViews?.firstIndex(where: { $0.bounds.contains(sender.location(in: $0)) }) else {
            // No image was tapped
            return
        }
        print("Image at index \(tappedImageIndex) was tapped")
    }
    
}
```

If images are overlapping and `firstIndex` is not appropriate then you can still get all the image views within the hit area and process them better.

On the other hand if you have more information you could compute the index possibly like so:

```
@objc private func onImageTapped2(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    let rowHeight = 200 // Depends on your grid layout
    let columnWidth = 200 // Depends on your grid layout
    let itemsPerRow = 3
    
    let positionInScrollView = sender.location(in: scrollView)
    
    let row = Int(positionInScrollView.y/CGFloat(rowHeight))
    let column = Int(positionInScrollView.x/CGFloat(columnWidth))
    
    let tappedImageIndex = row*itemsPerRow + column
    
    guard tappedImageIndex < imageViews?.count ?? 0 else {
        // No image was tapped
        return
    }
    print("Image at index \(tappedImageIndex) was tapped")
}
```

If required you can go into deeper levels using tools like the following:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let pressLocation = touches.first?.location(in: self) else { return }
    let locationInScrollView = self.convert(pressLocation, to: scrollView)
    // Do stuff here with
}
```